# MS Word 2007--Spacing between headers using "stylized" styles

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, styles, headers, line-spacing

We have a document with Styles: Heading 2, Heading 3 and Heading 4 that have color blocks around them and the double-line style border at the top and bottom of the paragraph. These styles work great when the are alone, but when they are adjacent to each other in the document, the borders disappear between the styles. We have manually dealt with this by adding "false spacing" (hard return) between them and reducing the font size of that space to 2, however, we would rather have this be automated for the usual reasons.

Adding "Before" and "After" spacing to the paragraph style does not help either.

I can't post pictures due to new status, but can send them.

Is there anyway to fix this problem using the styles settings?

[image: SU512397 example]

Comment: You can upload the images to any image host (http://imgur.com for example) and add the links to your question.

Comment: We can also help if you can upload the document somewhere for testing.